# tooling_1.constructorParametersDownlevelTransform is not a function

Tags: angular, deployment

tengo un proyecto que he estado revisando y arreglando errores de lógica y diseño que se cometieron al momento de crear el proyecto, ahora que trate de compilarlo con ng build --prod me tira el error de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun lo que he investigado es a causa de una actualización de angular 7 al 9 como puedo corregir este error o como puedo regresar angular a la version original del proyecto?